# If $U$ is a real measurable function s.t. $\int_{B_1(x)}\frac{1}{U(y)} dy\to 0$, does $\int_{B_1(x)}\frac{1}{U(y)+a} dy\to 0$, too?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $U:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ a measurable function such that
$${\rm infess}_{\mathbb{R}^N} U(x)>-\infty.$$
Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ be sufficiently large such that
$${\rm infess}_{\mathbb{R}^N} (U(x)+a)>0.$$
Finally, assume that
$$(I) \int_{B_1(x)}\frac{1}{U(y)} dy\to 0 \quad\mbox{ as } |x|\to +\infty.$$
My question is: assumption $(I)$ implies that also
$$\int_{B_1(x)}\frac{1}{U(y)+a} dy\to 0 \quad\mbox{ as } |x|\to +\infty?$$

If yes, how to prove it? I’ve been stuck for a while on it, I hope someone could help.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume infess$_{\mathbb{R}^N}$ means the '[essential infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_infimum_and_essential_supremum)' taken over $\mathbb{R}^N$, and $B_1(x)$ means the open ball of radius $1$ centered at $x$. Please correct me if I misunderstood them.

In the simplest case where $N=1$ we already can construct a counterexample. The idea is that $U$ (hence $1/U$) may oscillate to change sign over the balls, causing the cancellation between the positive and negative integrals. For example, $\int_{(-1,1)}\sin(2\pi x)dx=0$. In fact I'm going to construct a counterexample based on the sine function.

Let $\phi:\left(0,2\pi\right)\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by
\begin{align}
\phi(x):=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccl}
\frac{1}{2} & \text{if} & x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{6}\right)
\cup\left(\frac{5\pi}{6},\pi\right) \\
\sin x & \text{if} & x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}\right]
\cup\left[\frac{7\pi}{6},\frac{11\pi}{6}\right] \\
-\frac{1}{2} & \text{if} & x\in\left(\pi,\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)
\cup\left(\frac{11\pi}{6},2\pi\right) \\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
Plotting the graph and you can see that I'm merely modifying the graph of sine function near the points where it is zero by some nonzero constants ($\pm 1/2$). Then, let $\Phi$ be the $2\pi$-extension of $\phi$ to the whole real line. (Actually I have not defined $\Phi$ on the set $Z:=\{x:sin x=0\}=\{k\pi:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, but this is a set of measure zero and you are free to define anything you like on it, since the integral won't be affected.) Finally, set
\begin{align}
U(x):=\frac{1}{\Phi(2\pi x)}
\end{align}
Then $U$ is a measurable function satisfying
\begin{align}
\text{infess}_{\mathbb{R}}U=-2>-\infty
\end{align}
(This is the reason why I modify the sine function to be nonzero near points of $Z$. Had this not been done and we naively set $\Phi(x)=\sin x$, $U$ would not be essentially bounded below.) Choosing, e.g. $a=3$ will guarantee that infess$_{\mathbb{R}}(U+a)>0$.

Now, the periodicity of $\Phi$, hence of $U$, will imply that condition $(I)$ holds, by forcing the stronger fact that
\begin{align}
\int_{B_1(x)}\frac{1}{U(y)}dy=\int^{x+1}_{x-1}\Phi(2\pi y)dy=0
\end{align}
for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, since $\Phi(2\pi y)$ has period $1$, but the interval $B_1(x)=(x-1,x+1)$ has length $2$, and also due to the fact that
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi}_0\phi(x)dx=-\int^{2\pi}_{\pi}\phi(x)dx
\end{align}
However, on the other hand we can show that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{U(y)+a}=\frac{\Phi(2\pi y)}{1+3\Phi(2\pi y)}
\end{align}
has a positive lower bound (says $c>0$) on $\mathbb{R}\setminus Z$, and so the integral
\begin{align}
\int_{B_1(x)}\frac{1}{U(y)+a}dy\geq c\cdot\text{length}B_1(x)=2c
\end{align}
is bounded below by a positive constant for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, hence cannot tend to $0$ as $|x|\to+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am going to check it with all the details before accepting (but it seems correct to me to a first sight). May I ask if you are thinking about some further assumptions on $U$ which could imply that $\int_{B_1(x)} \frac{1}{U(x)+a}dx \to 0$ as $|x|\to +\infty$?

Comment: @C.Bishop No problem, you should definitely check it rigorously and let me know if there's any error =) Well, since the claim fails because $U$ are allowed to oscillate and change signs, one natural further assumption is of course to assume $U$ has definite sign, says e.g. it is a non-negative function, but I'm not sure if this is too restrictive for your purpose.

Comment: Hopf eccentric, thank you. I have a question about your answer. Could you please help me to understand why $\int_{x-1}^{x+1} \Phi(2\pi y)dy =0$. And why you say that $\Phi(2\pi y)$ has period $1$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hopf eccentric, one more question about your comment. What do you mean with "$U$ has definite sign"? If I ask to be always negative, I ask $a\in\mathbb{R}$ exists such that $\infess (U+a)>0$ and condition $(I)$ holds, it would be enough to have the desired result?

Comment: @C.Bishop The function $\Phi(x)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, so $\Phi(2\pi x)$ has period $1$, as you can check easily: $\Phi(2\pi(x+1))=\Phi(2\pi x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. For a periodic function $f$ with period $L$, we have $\int_{[x,x+L]}f=\int_{[0,L]}f$, so it suffices to compute $\int^1_0\Phi(2\pi y)dy$, which you can split into $\int^{1/2}_0\Phi(2\pi y)dy$ and $\int^1_{1/2}\Phi(2\pi y)dy$. They have the same magnitude but with opposite sign, hence cancel out each other. (I hope my computation is correct, lol)

Comment: @C.Bishop By "$U$ has definite sign" i simply means either $U\geq 0$ everywhere or $U\leq 0$ everywhere. Having a more careful thought about it, I think if $U\leq 0$, then we need one more condition that $a$ is chosen large enough so that $|U+a|\geq|U|$ everywhere (or at least outside a large ball $B_R(0)$). so that $\left|\int_{B_1(x)}\frac{1}{U+a}\right|\leq\int_{B_1(x)}\frac{1}{|U+a|}\leq\int_{B_1(x)}\frac{1}{|U|}=-\int_{B_1(x)}\frac{1}{U}\to 0$ as $|x|\to+\infty$. So merely having a definite sign may still not enough in this case, sorry about that.

Comment: Hopf eccentric, so sorry about this stupid question. If $U$ is always negative, I can always assume that $a\in\mathbb{R}$ exists such that ${\rm infess}(U+a)>0$, isn't it?

Comment: @C.Bishop No worry at all. As long as $\text{infess }U>-\infty$ (i.e. $U$ is essentially bounded from below), the answer is affirmative. Btw I should also be more precise that every 'everywhere' should be replaced by 'almost everywhere', lol.